# Merge two different Python RexEx search

Tags: python

**Issues with Python Regex...**

1. Need to combine these two regex searches into one (it should work
   based on my two different input mystring)
2. Not sure why first search is always considering second set of
   brackets (refer the oracle alert)
3. However my second search is correctly returning the string from
   first set of brackets (refer Mongo)

**Appreciate any help here...**

```
import re
mystring="<https://myurl:6001/alerts|ebe182d2> [Open] Oracle Memory Alert - [Alerting] Oracle Memory Alert"
a=re.compile('<.*\|(.*)>.*\[(.*)\].*([O|o]racle).*(Memory Alert)')

matches=a.search(mystring)
if matches:
 print("matching")
 print("ID=",matches.group(1),"Status=",matches.group(2),"alert=",matches.group(3))
else:
 print("no match")

mystring="<https://myurl:6001/alerts|xvf381h1> [Open] Mongo Disk Alert - [Causing] Disk is full"
a=re.compile('<.*\|(.*)>.*\[(.*)\].*([M|m]ongo).*(Disk Alert)')
matches=a.search(mystring)
if matches:
 print("matching")
 print("ID=",matches.group(1),"Status=",matches.group(2),"alert=",matches.group(3))
else:
 print("no match")
```

Output:

```
matching
ID= ebe182d2 Status= Alerting alert= Oracle
matching
ID= xvf381h1 Status= Open alert= Mongo
```

Comment: What are your constraints?  How important are each of these?
1) speed for positive matches
2) speed for negative matches
3) readability
4) ability to add additional cases (how many in the foreseeable future)?
5) algorithm coolness.   What is the approximate ratio of successes to total strings tested?

Comment: The answer to #2 and #3 is the fact that you're using greedy matches, which causes the first case to find the second instance of "Oracle Memory Alert" rather than the first.  This doesn't come up in the second case because "Mongo Disk Alert" only appears once in your test string. -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that fixes the #2 issue by making your matching less greedy.  It's better to change both patterns, as it makes the second one more correct even if you get the right result either way:

```
import re

mystring = "<https://myurl:6001/alerts|ebe182d2> [Open] Oracle Memory Alert - [Alerting] Oracle Memory Alert"
a = re.compile('<.*\|(.*)>.*?\[(.*?)\].*?([O|o]racle).*?(Memory Alert)')

matches = a.search(mystring)
if matches:
    print("matching")
    print("ID=", matches.group(1), "Status=", matches.group(2), "alert=", matches.group(3))
else:
    print("no match")

mystring = "<https://myurl:6001/alerts|xvf381h1> [Open] Mongo Disk Alert - [Causing] Disk is full"
a = re.compile('<.*\|(.*)>.*?\[(.*?)\].*?([M|m]ongo).*?(Disk Alert)')
matches = a.search(mystring)
if matches:
    print("matching")
    print("ID=", matches.group(1), "Status=", matches.group(2), "alert=", matches.group(3))
else:
    print("no match")
```

Output:

```
matching
('ID=', 'ebe182d2', 'Status=', 'Open', 'alert=', 'Oracle')
matching
('ID=', 'xvf381h1', 'Status=', 'Open', 'alert=', 'Mongo')
```

To give you some idea of where I'm going with my questions (in my comments)...if you care about speed, you only ever want to search for these two cases, and you believe that the substrings "Oracle Memory Alert" and "Mongo Disk Alert" will show up very infrequently, then you're better off just looking for those strings without regular expressions at all.  If you find them, THEN you apply the regex tests to see if the candidate matches really do match.  Depending on what you know about your dataset, there are lots of ways to highly optimize your test.  For example, you don't need to start looking for these two patterns at the beginning of the strings.  Presumably you could come up with a place to start looking in the string that you are comfortable would always put you before those patterns occurred.

If what you want to match occurs relatively infrequently, then ALL you care about in terms of performance is the speed of knowing the string DOESN'T match for most, but not necessarily all cases.  You want to think about how to exclude a large % of your strings very quickly.  Once you fail to exclude the string, it doesn't really matter how long it takes to determine if it's really a match, if you only get that far once in a blue moon.

If you don't care about speed, but just readability, then the best thing is to probably test each case individually using pretty much what you have right now.  Most optimization you'd do will make the code less readable.

There are probably dozens, if not hundreds, of potentially "correct" solutions to this problem.  It all depends on the characteristics of your data set as to which one is best.  It's not often you come across a problem like this that doesn't have a single or a few right answers.

Give me some more information, and I can help you optimize this per your requirements.

Oh...and here's a kinda/sorta answer to #1.  I make extra assumptions that a) you won't see lowercase Mongo or Oracle, and b) The spaces between the words are consistently a single character.  If you can make those two assumptions, then this expression is MUCH faster than your original two.  You'd have to adjust your logic to take just the first word of the two main matches.  Again though, if you hardly ever see these strings, the time it takes to do that is irrelevant.

```
a = re.compile('<.*\|(.*)>.*?\[(.*?)\].*?(Oracle Memory Alert|Mongo Disk Alert)')
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for the quick turnaround. I am yet to collect the list of items similar to the example which I shared. I believe the list to grow upto 50 alerts.

Comment: Solving #1 for 50 alerts makes it a different problem than the one you're showing me.  With that said, I expect that you could make generalizations about your data that would let you come up with a single expression.  Just don't be too hung up on that.  There's nothing inherently wrong with doing multiple tests if you can usually exclude ever getting that far.

Comment: I'm really curious.  Do you have any idea what the eventual ratio will be between matches and non-matches?

Comment: Yep, you are right! I will make more testing and find out all combinations to figure out the one common expression. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe the non-match situation will be very less, but yet to finalize it.

Comment: "I believe the non-match situation will be very less".  Wow.  Then if you care about getting the best performance possible, this isn't so easy a problem.  The easy problems are when you can quickly exclude most of your strings.  - I hope I've given you good stuff to think about.  The best solution for your needs may be nothing like what I've shown you here.  (PS: I'm known in my professional circles as a "regex weenie" :) )

Comment: Refer below sample format.  mystring="<https://myurl:6001/alerts|xvf381h1> [Open] Oracle Disk Alert - [Causing] Mongo Disk is full". The previously provided Regex searching is to second set of  square brackets. How to search the next word right after first set of square brackets (which is "Oracle", shouldn't be Mongo)